# Invalid data table format: column #2 must be of type 'date,number,datetime'.×

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization, timeline

I have the following data. If I am trying to generate it using PHP, it's showing me this error:

> Invalid data table format: column #2 must be of type
>   'date,number,datetime'.

```
chartData: [
    [ 'Action', '',       new Date(0,0,0,12,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0) ],
    [ 'Action', '',    new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,15,30,0) ],
    [ 'Action', '',        new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,17,30,0) ],
    [ 'Navigation',   'home',    new Date(0,0,0,12,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0) ],
    [ 'Navigation',   'slider', new Date(0,0,0,14,1,0), new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0) ],
    [ 'Navigation',   'foodMenu',     new Date(0,0,0,16,1,0), new Date(0,0,0,18,0,0) ],
    [ 'Heart Beat', '',       new Date(0,0,0,12,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0) ],
    [ 'Heart Beat', '',    new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,15,30,0) ],
    [ 'Heart Beat', '',        new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,17,30,0) ]]
```

That's my PHP code:

```
$data = [[ 'Action', '',       'new Date(0,0,0,12,0,0)',  'new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0)' ],
    [ 'Action', '',    'new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0)',  'new Date(0,0,0,15,30,0)' ],
    [ 'Action', '',        'new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0)',  'new Date(0,0,0,17,30,0)' ],
    [ 'Navigation',   'home',    'new Date(0,0,0,12,30,0)', 'new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0)' ],
    [ 'Navigation',   'slider', 'new Date(0,0,0,14,1,0)', 'new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0)' ],
    [ 'Navigation',   'foodMenu',     'new Date(0,0,0,16,1,0)', 'new Date(0,0,0,18,0,0)' ],
    [ 'Heart Beat', '',       'new Date(0,0,0,12,0,0)',  'new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0)' ],
    [ 'Heart Beat', '',    'new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0)',  'new Date(0,0,0,15,30,0)' ],
    [ 'Heart Beat', '',        'new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0)',  'new Date(0,0,0,17,30,0)' ]];

$jsonTable = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: That error message is not present in your given code

Comment: i am using google timeline https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use the `new` keywords on dates when passing json as a string.

instead, use google's [date string](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#dates-and-times-using-the-date-string-representation) representation,
which basically just drops the `new` keyword.

```
"Date(0,0,0,12,0,0)"
```

however, in order to use the above,
you will need to use the json format found here (ignore the date example here)...

[Format of the Data Table Constructor's JavaScript Literal data Parameter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)